Company Created Position For Me, Tried to Sell Me On It, Then Rejected Me
About a month and a half ago, I interviewed with Company X for a position as an Engineering Manager. After a typical gauntlet of interviews, I was told that while I performed extremely well, they would make the offer to another candidate with more extensive experience.
Disappointing, but I appreciated the transparency—not much I can do about that. I thanked them, and they told me they’d keep me on speed-dial if things fell through as they still really liked how I performed.
A few weeks later, I got a call from them that that offer was signed, but they liked my candidacy enough that they wanted to carve out a new position on the team for me as a tech lead. While it was technically a demotion on the management track, it was equivalent pay, I liked the company, and figured I could still enjoy the work. I accepted.
Next, they informed me of two final interviews, as the others were redundant. One, with the head of the department, and an additional technical interview.
The first was optional and only for me to ask questions about the nature of the new role—it was essentially to sell me on continuing. I wasn’t even asked any questions, the interviewer presented themselves as a total open book.
The second was a fairly simple coding interview which was a home run in my view. A simple problem which I solved quickly, and the interviewer praised my creative thinking. A verbatim quote: “you’ve clearly done this before.”
So imagine my surprise to hear back a rejection! The recruiter said, to paraphrase, “we really wanted to hire you for this role but unfortunately we can’t move forward. We hope you don’t mind if we reach out in the future.”
I’m completely gobsmacked to hear this. I’m used to rejection on a job hunt, but I can’t quite comprehend how I could have possibly bungled this. I’m also very upset and disappointed to have been strung along like this only to get the vaguest possible explanation.
What could possibly be going on here? This is the most psychologically damaging process I’ve been a part of, because I received nothing but positive feedback and transparency up until exactly this point. What stings is how eager they were to tell me about the internal machinations of their process, but have neglected to tell me if it was something I did or the budget simply dried up.

VTC - The only people that can answer why are the company themselves. However, what I suspect happened is that everyone within the immediate management chain or branch or department was keen... And someone else (who they thought would be on board) wasnt. It can feel disheartening.

Definitely disheartening! I think your theory makes sense. Still, I can’t help but feel resentment for not having that confirmed before the offer to interview.

@Eee, it's far from clear that you were actually rejected. It sounds like someone wanted to get you in the door, but someone else has either kyboshed the position itself (unrelated to your merit), or may just have felt it was bad karma to mix you with the new manager who nabbed the position you actually wanted.

If your assessment of your interviews is correct, this likely simply has internal reasons:

The budget might have been cut
some higher up might have objected to increase the team size independent of the person
the project might have been gotten a different priority
they might have realized internal resources got freed up and they needed to place them somewhere - taking your role


That would be disappointing, but understandable. While it would be callous to me personally, I also have to wonder about the huge waste of time for everybody else if that were the case.

@Eee: At the end of the day, it was also a waste of time to the people who were in the process of hiring you - probably more time wasted on their part combined than on yours. It sucks but such is the nature of pre-contract negotiations. You can't only allow customers in your shop if they promise to buy something.


but unfortunately we can’t move forward. We hope you don’t mind if we reach out in the future.

The fact that they're not dismissing you as a candidate (wanting to reach out in the future) suggests that the reason they can't move forward isn't you, it's something else.
Given that they were creating a position to hire you in the first place, my money is on them being overly creative with their hiring budget and justification for this extra role, and someone in upper management stopped this process in its track. But that's just an educated guess.

What stings is how they [..] have neglected to tell me if it was something I did or the budget simply dried up.

Being more specific doesn't fix anything for them. If the reason is that they tried hiring you against company rules, admitting to it would generate evidence of them trying to break the rules. If the reason is that the company genuinely intended to hire you and something changed, then they would be admitting a weakness and revealing internal office politics to an outsider.
If the reason is that you're not cut out for the job, not all companies spend the effort to give you constructive feedback for your personal benefit, they stop at the "not for us" decision. While I wouldn't expect them to then suggest that they may reach out to you in the future; it's similarly possible that they might have you pegged for a different role (e.g. if they feel you have no leadership skills but good development skills, they might want to offer you a dev job down the line).
In either case, I wouldn't take it personally. Whether or not you will remain available and willing in case they call you up again, is completely your call to make.
